# how to search all user meta data that have value like "vivek"

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, json

I want to search all users metadata that have meta value like "**vivek**" if the mata key are "**submitted**"  and the meta value store in a serialized format

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'submitted',
        'value' => 'vivek',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said data is stored inside meta_value as serialized format. You can match your string among the serialized string like data.

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'submitted',
        'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', 'vivek'),
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Hope this help!